# Replacing an old WP site with a new updated site

Tags: wordpress, migration, database-migration

So i'm looking to replace an old site with a newly built site. Both sites are built in WP. The urls are set up like this: "oldsite.org" and "oldsite.org/new"

I need to replace the old site with the new site so that /new is not required to get to the right place. What's the most efficient way of going about this? My client says has has a couple of back-end developers attempt this already and both failed due to faulty plug-ins. Import/Export attempts have previously broken the site.

Comment: This question is very broad and there are a lot of unknowns here. Moving WP installations around is commonplace, so the fact that import/export attempts have previously failed suggests there is more to this than meets the eye. I'd suggest reading this first https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Answer (score 0):

You can go for a simple solution. Please find that step wise :

1. Take a backup of current site.
2. Install **WP CLONE ACADEMY** plugin into your new site.
3. Clone the new site
4. Install the same plugin into old site.
5. Import the clone file into old site.

Everything will imported from new site to old, even the database, plugins and etc.

Hope this will help you.